# Spring. Как вывести ошибку поля, если на странице имеется несколько однотипных форм?

Tags: spring, jsp, form, валидация

Имеется таблица в JSP. В каждой строке таблицы выводится форма с одинаковым modelAttribute, когда в контроллер возвращает страницу с ошибкой формы, то она отображается рядом с каждой формой, а не рядом с той у которой возникла ошибка.
Как это исправить?

В контроллере так генерируется ошибка:

```
bindingResult.rejectValue("description", null, "Error field description");
```

JSP:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 60%;">Наименование</th>
        <th style="width: 40%;">Действия</th>        
    </tr>    
    <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers.list}">
        <tr>
            <td>${customer.name}</td>                        
            <td>
                <form:form id="${customer.id}_form_id"
                           modelAttribute="customer_extra"                           
                           method="POST"
                           action="?">
                    <input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="${customer.id}" />
                    <div>                        
                        <form:input path="description" type="text"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="form-error">
                        <form:errors path="description" cssClass="block-error"/>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправить можно, добавив условие на соответствие идентификатора бина строчке в таблице:

```
<c:if test="${customer.id == customer_extra.id}">
    <div class="form-error">
        <form:errors path="description" cssClass="block-error"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
```